# How can I get riak-js to return walked objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, riak, riak-js

I'm using a Riak database from Node via riak-js.  I have two buckets: `invites` and `events.`  Invites has a link to events.  I'd really like to retrieve the invite object and the corresponding event object in one query.  To this end, I've tried this:

```
db.walk("invites", inviteKey, 
[{ bucket: 'events', tag: 'event', keep: true}], 
   function (err, result, meta) { /* ... */ });
```

But that just gives me the Event corresponding to the invite, it doesn't give me the Invite.  I'm guessing the `keep` attribute is either not meant to go there, or is being ignored for some reason.  Is there a way to do this?   The Riak-js documentation is difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in Riak link walking rather than in the client library. You can get results from the various link walking steps returned, but not the object you started with.